# Can't make firebase signout inside fragment

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I click on SignOut but I don't know if it logs out or not because I stay in the same fragment.

I want to go to the SignInActivity page when I log out, but it doesn't go and stays in the same fragment. That's my problem.

What could be the reason?

```
class HomePageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var authStateListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
            if (user == null) {
                val intent = Intent(this, SignInActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
             }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}


MyAccountFragment  ---->
                   

class MyAccountFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var authStateListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
            if (user == null) {
                val intent = Intent(activity, SignInActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.my_account_toolbar)

        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_account_fragment_menu)

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_account_fragment_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.SignOut -> {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) is a bit different from the Activity Lifecycle. Consider using `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreate` and `onViewDestroyed` instead of `onStop`. And you'd call `addAuthStateListener()` in `onViewCreated`.

Comment: Have you tried Rosário's suggestion?

Comment: no , i tried a lot of code but still couldn't solve the problem.